# I am using POI 4.1.0 version. While using shiftRows(), the excel file is getting corrupt

Tags: java, excel, spring-tool-suite, apache-poi-4

```
for (int i = 0; i < newSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            if (.....) {
                newSheet.removeRow(newSheet.getRow(i));
                newSheet.shiftRows(i+1, newSheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
                i--;
            }   
        }
```

It's not giving any compilation error or runtime error but the excel file I'm working on is getting corrupt.

It's showing this messgae while opening file-

Error when opening in Excel:

> Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

So any bug fixes on this available or what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of Apache POI release version 4.1.0, there is a bug in the `XSSFSheet shiftRows();` that has not been fixed yet. There is currently a bug entered for tracking and remediation [Here](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Bug-62711-New-Calling-shiftRows-corrupts-file-in-POI-4-0-td5731583.html).

Until it is fixed, I recommend downgrading your POI JAR version to 3.17 (see this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980407/apache-poi-shiftrows-corrupts-file-and-deletes-content)) or use a version of the fix shown in the same post by "Axel Richter".

Hopefully, Apache will soon have the bug fixed in a newer release.

Comment: Yes. The issue is resolved already and I had implemented it in this way only.

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"Hmmm… can't reach this page | DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"*.